# Foreign key references a many-to-may table (Reinforces the access right)

Tags: database-design, foreign-key, many-to-many

I have this scenario in an e-commerce project:

`Category` table, `Store` table, and `Bid` table.

So, it should work like this:

`categories` are at the top.
`stores` can have many `categories` (let's name it `stores_allowed_categories`) and it's designed as an associative table `many-to-many` containing two columns `store_id` and `category_id`, till now I believe I'm doing fine.

Now a challenge is with the `Bid` table:

- Each `Bid` record has one `Store` (a simple `one-to-many` relationship designed as a foreign key `store_id` on the `Bid` table)
- And must have an `category_id` from the `allowed_categories`
  assigned to the `store` specified.

What I did here is the following:

I created a foreign key column `category_id` on the `Bid` table which references directly the `Category` table. And tried to manage every strange case on the programming language side.

After a few months, things were uncomfortable for me and I felt that I have done something wrong, and released that the relationship should be between the `Bid` and `stores_allowed_categories` (the `many-to-many` associative table between `Store` and `Category`), and by doing this, the database will save me a lot of hard coding the cases.

I would really appreciate your help, I have two questions:

- Is what I did a bad practice?
- What is the best practice to design such kind of scenario?

Thank you very much.

Comment: *the relationship should be between the Bid and stores_allowed_categories* This approach is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to use predicates and constraints to describe the problem, then a solution becomes obvious. As opposed to "I have tables, etc..".

---

```
-- Category CAT exists.
--
category {CAT}
      PK {CAT}
```

```
-- Store STO exists.
--
store {STO}
   PK {STO}
```

```
-- Store STO is of category CAT.
--
--
-- Each store may be of more than one category;
-- for each category, more than one store can be
-- of that category.
--
-- If a store is of a category, then that store must exist
-- and that category must exist.
--
--
store_category {STO, CAT}
            PK {STO, CAT}

FK1 {STO} REFERENCES store    {STO}
FK2 {CAT} REFERENCES category {CAT}
```

```
-- Bid number BNO is for store STO of category CAT.
--
-- Each bid is for exactly one store (of a category);
-- for each store, more than one bid may be for that store.
--
-- If a bid is for a store of a category, 
-- then that store must be of that category.
--
--
bid {BNO, STO, CAT}
 PK {BNO}

 FK {STO, CAT} REFERENCES store_category {STO, CAT}
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
FK = Foreign Key
```